# Filter all but postal codes on google maps api autocomplete

Tags: google-maps

So I'm trying to limit the search of google maps autocomplete. When you search, I only want it to autocomplete postal codes. I've read some of the API and am confused if I can do this with the api. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types

it says something about postal_codes but I'm not sure if it's for what I am trying to do.

If not, how can I achieve this?

I don't have any code, because I'm not quite sure where to start. I have a search functioning and it does the autocomplete but it's searching for everything. I just want postal codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line in your Http Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=SanFrancisco&types;=postal_code&key;=API_KEY
```

This pull out only the postal addresses in San Francisco when you start typing the digits in search box.